# Is there any way to automaticly add a product to a product-page when the product gets a special price?

Tags: category, price, sales, page

Is there any way that when I give a product a special price, it automatically adds the product to a special "Sale" page at my homepage without manually adding the product to any type of category? 
So that I can press the selected "Sale" page in the top and all the special priced items are on that page?

I hope someone can help! Thanks ;)

Rob

Comment: you need to let us know which version of Magento you are using?

Comment: What did you try so far? I think it is not possible without extensions or custom programming

Comment: sorry for the late reaction!! i'm using magento 1.9 currently.

Comment: I didn't do anything so far. I have a homepage slide with a few products, but that is from a category. I want a automatic sale slider without manually adding a product to a category